Table containing array/list errors as "code that is not properly formatted as code"
Summary
The following table fails formatting checks when I attempt to include it in a Stack Overflow answer. I am not sure how to format this table to avoid an error from Stack Overflow.
Expected Output is a formatted table (not a code block).



product_id
unique_node_values




1
[a_0, a_1]


2
[a_0, a_1]


3
[a_1, a_2]


7
[a_1, a_2]



To reproduce,
Step 1. Open Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/
Step 2. Open Questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
Step 3. Choose any question, Click Add Answer
Step 3. Copy Code block below and Paste into the Answer
|product_id|unique_node_values|
|----------|------------------|
|1         |[a_0, a_1]        |
|2         |[a_0, a_1]        |
|3         |[a_1, a_2]        |
|7         |[a_1, a_2]        |


Step 4. Receive Error Message
Error Message

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
toolbar icon.

The error message is confusing, since I do not expect this to be formatted as code and instead expect to be formatted as a table.
Context
The full Stack Overflow answer that I was trying to submit includes more than this table. What I shared here is a minimal reproducible example of the issue.
Screenshot
In the attached screenshot below I see the table format correctly, but still produce an error.

Example
In this Stack Overflow Answer. The table shared in this question will not format with arrays in a column as a normal string (however I did find a workaround using backticks). While other tables in this answer allow arrays in a column to format normally.

We get reports about false alarms from this error all the time, but I think this reproduction is novel.

Well, array/list representations are code so they should be formatted as such. Using backticks is not a workaround, it is exactly what you are supposed to do.
|product_id|unique_node_values|
|----------|------------------|
|`1`       |`[a_0, a_1]`      |
|`2`       |`[a_0, a_1]`      |
|`3`       |`[a_1, a_2]`      |
|`7`       |`[a_1, a_2]`      |

Note that the "code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut" indeed format the field content correctly, albeit not via 4 space indents.
While the format checker is not exactly perfect (*cough*) it seems to be right in this case. Rather than seeing this as a failure of the check because other tables are not flagged, consider the lack of flagging the other tables as a failure. Those should also properly formatted.

While this may be a fair reason to give the code-formatting checker a pass on this one, deliberately requiring that would be...aggressively prescriptive.  It's pretty similarly readable either way (and it's questionable whether the integer column really needs it, as you suggest).  There's also no non-incredibly-tedious way to add code formatting to the dozens of cells in that answer.

Upon further reflection, other cases of tables triggering this check had a lot of + symbols.  Some testing confirms that it's the square brackets (underscores didn't make any difference).  So yes, this answer is correct, even if the code-formatting checker is being somewhat aggressive in this case.
